# (VBA Commands Priority) How to firstly open excel files from internet explorer during vba runs?

Tags: excel, vba, process, operating-system

I am trying to open excel files downloded from internet and then copy the data into another excel file during vba runs with their commands.

But the command that open the excel file is executed after the ends of vba code regardless of their position.

For example, below code shows whole process of downloading and opening the excel file from a site. But at the "open_excel" function "InvokePattern.Invoke" actually occurs after the execution of all vba codes.

How do I execute this at first? Could I give some priority on that command?

Or how to wait on "InvokePattern.Invoke" until that finished?
(I try wait time or kinds of time manipulation which doesn't work)

```
Sub crawler_main() ' this is main function

    .....
    Call ieopen(ie, url_futures) 'internet explorer is opened with some url 
    Call click_excel(ie)
    Call open_excel(ie)
    Call copy_data(wbname)
    .....

End Sub

Sub ieopen(ie As InternetExplorer, url As String) ' open ie

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate url

    Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
End Sub

Sub click_excel(ie As InternetExplorer) 'download excel

    Dim inquiry As Object
    Set inquiry = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-board btn-board-search")(0)
    inquiry.Click

    Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    Dim Buttons_Excel As Object
    Dim Button As Object
    Set Buttons_Excel = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

    For Each Button In Buttons_Excel
        If Button.innerHTML = "Excel" Then
            Button.FireEvent ("onclick")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub open_excel(ie As InternetExplorer) 'click open in dialog open/save

    Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim o As CUIAutomation
    Set o = New CUIAutomation

    Dim h As Long

    h = ie.hwnd
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)

    If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
    Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "열기")

    Dim Button_Download As IUIAutomationElement
    Set Button_Download = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)

    Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Set InvokePattern = Button_Download.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)

    InvokePattern.Invoke

End Sub

Sub copy_data(wbname As String) 'copy data from recently opened file. 
'But here is problematic since file is open after the execution of all vba codes

     For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
         If wb.Name Like "dat" & "*" Then
             Set wb_data = Workbooks(wb.Name)
             Exit For
         End If
     Next wb

     ............

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr...87(VS.85).aspx

Note that you can use realtime which is higher but you will have to set permissions to do so...
Code:

```
Sub SetPriority()
    Const ABOVE_NORMAL = 32768
    Const HIGH = 128
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
        & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'excel.exe'")
    For Each objProcess In colProcesses
        objProcess.SetPriority (HIGH)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for a commnet, But url is collapsed, could you give me a full address?